# Why it shows two AppBars after adding 'Sliver AppBar' in flutter App

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have added 'Sliver AppBar' into Scaffold of my app and I am wondering why it shows two app bars now. The Scaffold contains only one drawer but in UI , it shows two drawers. Anybody know what is going wrong.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        bottom: AppBar(
          title: SizedBox(
            height: 45,
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, left: 15),
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  onPressed: () {
                  },
                ),
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                hintText: "What are you looking for ?",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          
        ),
      ),
      
  drawer: Drawer(),
  
);
```

[image]

After removing SliverAppBar from the code, it shows blank screen. So, it is confirmed that the two AppBars are coming from above code only.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SliverAppBar` itself a `appBar` and `bottom: AppBar` is another one, you can use `PreferredSize` on `bottom`.

```dart
SliverAppBar(
  bottom: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(45),
    child: TextField(
```

Comment: Thanks @Yeasin  , it works.                                               
   SliverAppBar(
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(45),
              child: SizedBox(
                  height: 45,
                  child: TextField(